# Перезапуск по расписанию в Linux

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Нужн оперезапускать asterisk каждый час, сделал скрипт

```
#!/bin/bash

 /etc/init.d/asterisk  restart
```

Поместил в `/etc/cron.hourly`

Проблема, в том, что вариант не устраивает, хочу не форс ребут делать, а `gracefully`, что возможно только из под **Asterisk CLI**. Сделать надо "прямо сейчас", не могу искать в книгах и прочих источниках.

То есть скрипт должен выполнять всего две команды

`asterisk -rv
core restart gracefully`

Но вот каким образом передать вторую команду в CLI не могу найти инфу.

Сижу под CentOS 6.5

P.S. Обязательно прочитаю Advanced Bash Scripting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Команда asterisk -rvx "core restart gracefully" должна помочь.
Параметр -x указывает передать команду в CLI.

Comment: Спасибо, пытался так-же, только без х, этот параметр работает со всеми подобными случаями, когда команду надо выполнить в оболочке другой прогаммы?

Comment: А нет, не может, вроде нашел инфу, по параметрам

Answer (score 1):

asterisk -rx "core restart gracefully"